# Disassociate DatePickers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

I have a table that renders a partial for each member.

`_partial.cshtml`:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Effective Date
    </td>
    <td />
    <td class="date @Model.GroupId">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EffectiveDate)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Term Date
    </td>
    <td />
    <td class="date @Model.GroupId">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TermDate)
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to use a datepicker for datefield but when selecting on the subsequent datefields they all only affect the first of their type. i.e any `StartDate` field will change the first `StartDate` on the screen not itself.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".32 input").datepicker();

$(".6 input").datepicker();

});
```

Comment: I don't think a css class name can start with a number. Did you try changing the classes to .group-32 and .group-6?

Comment: @George I belive your right thanks for pointing that out. Yet my problem still remains after making that change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there might be an issue with each of your input boxes getting the same id (they'd all be `id="EffectiveDate"` or `id="TermDate"`), which is invalid, and then datepicker grabbing the first one w/ that id.

Comment: I think you right thats why i was trying to differentiate with with class. Since I haven't found a way to overload the naming of the controls.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have attached the datepicker to the `<td>` whereas normally it should be associated with the input field. Also you don't need those `@Model.GroupId` in the class names:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Effective Date
    </td>
    <td />
    <td class="date">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EffectiveDate)
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Term Date
    </td>
    <td />
    <td class="date">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TermDate)
    </td>
</tr>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('.date input').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I've tried your approach and it still behaves in the same manner.